# Recvfrom function not receiving data

Tags: c++

This is my first time posting so hopefully I'm doing it right. I've been browsing the site trying to find an answer to this problem, but I'm at a loss.

I developed some UDP code in C++ in Linux on a Raspberry Pi, that's supposed to receive from something on Windows. If it matters, I'm using Remote Desktop to access the Pi from the same computer the code is on. Due to other problems, I can't simply put this code on the Pi.

I can create a socket, `bind()` it, and do everything up to the point where the `recvfrom()` function is supposed to grab the data. At this point, it simply stops working. There's no error, it just won't display anything below it, even an `if` statement for `if recvfrom` is -1.

I've tried making it blocking and non-blocking, changing the variable names, and plopping this part of the code down in its own separate file to debug, but it still won't receive anything. I know the server code works fine.

This isn't my first time working with UDP, but I'm also not super experienced, and I don't know what could be causing this issue. There's another UDP function in the code that works.

Why aren't I receiving data, and how can I fix it?

```c
    int PORT = 20016;

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    memset((char *) &serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    int packetSize = 36;
    char packetData[packetSize];

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress;
    socklen_t caddr_length= sizeof clientAddress;

    handle = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
    if(handle < 0)
    {
        perror("socket\n");
        exit;
    }

    if ( bind( handle, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress) ) < 0 )
    {
        perror("bind failure\n");
        exit;
    }

    while ( 1 )
    {
        cout << "receiving data..." << endl;
        int received_bytes = recvfrom(handle, packetData, sizeof(packetData),0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &caddr_length);
        if ( received_bytes == -1)
        {
            cout << "Data not received: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Data incoming:" << endl;

            int *dataPacket=(int *)packetData;

            a = dataPacket[0];
            b = dataPacket[1];  
            c = dataPacket[2];  
            d = dataPacket[3];  
            e = dataPacket[4];  
            f = dataPacket[5];  
            g = dataPacket[6];  
            h = dataPacket[7];  
            i = dataPacket[8];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you send data to your program?

Comment: What do you mean by "I know the server code works fine.". Your program is the server here.

Comment: Sorry, I tend to confuse server and client. So I have a C++ code on Windows that sends the data using UDP. I know the data is being sent correctly from that program, or at the very least, isn't the problem, because I wrote it as a work-around to another program that doesn't work with our pi's operating system (had the same problem, actually)

Comment: Suggest a stop by [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) (best on the net) You seem to be using the old approach populating `struct sockaddr_in` manually. That has largely been replaced by `getaddrinfo()` which simplifies the process.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Do not cut off parts you think are useless such as `#include` directives.

Comment: What port is the client sending *from*? What port is the client sending *to*?

Comment: `char packetData[packetSize];` is not legal C++. `exit;` does nothing whatsoever.

Comment: The program does in fact receive data, tested with [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). Closing as not reproducible.